# Calculating stock weight for SEC13F filers

Tags: portfolio, price

I am trying to evaluate weight of stocks in portfolio for an investor. For this purpose 
I use SEC13F filings for particular quarters and historical prices from Yahoo. There are stocks in portfolio which have zero volume from time to time.  Is it correct to use price when volume is zero? Should I just ignore these stocks?